# Real time database firebase

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I have some problems with Real time Database of Firebase for my Android App, because I can’t see any data. I don’t know why, I have also changed the rules yet.
I have three classes in my Android project: LogIn, SignUp (for registration) and Profile. When I write "name", "username","lastname", "email" and "password" in the SignUp class, then I can see the "name" "lastname" and "username" in the Profile, but not in the Real time DataBase.
Here there is part of the code:

SignUp:
declaration of variables:

```
 private lateinit var dbReference: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var firebaseDatabase: FirebaseDatabase
```

and then.....

```
   rebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            dbReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("users")
            dbReference.setValue("First users")
    
     val currentDb = dbReference.child((currentUser?.uid!!))
                            currentDb.child("name").setValue(name)
                            currentDb.child("lastname").setValue(lastName)
                            currentDb.child("user").setValue(user)
                            currentDb.child("email").setValue(email)
                            currentDb.child("pass").setValue(pass)
```

Profile class:
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
databaseReference = database?.reference!!.child("users")

```
   override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
       val usernameText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.usernameText)
                        val nameText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.nameText)
                        val lastnameText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.lastnameText)
                        usernameText.text =  snapshot.child("user").value?.toString()
                        nameText.text=  snapshot.child("name").value?.toString()
                        lastnameText.text=  snapshot.child("lastname").value?.toString()
            }
```

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/liW2z.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this in ur Signup:

```
private lateinit var dbReference: DatabaseReference
dbReference = Firebase.database.reference;
dbReference.child("users").setValue("First users")
```

instead of

```
private lateinit var dbReference: DatabaseReference
private lateinit var firebaseDatabase: FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
dbReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("users")
dbReference.setValue("First users")
```

you may have jumbled up java and kotlin code. As shown in the page https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

[image]

---

---

---

UPDATE :

I would like to add something. I didnt see this at first but it seems important and is mentioned in page  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

[image]

Can you try this

```
dbReference = Firebase.database("https://soundbliss-8ba73-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app").reference;
```

instead of

```
dbReference = Firebase.database.reference;
```

If this doesn't work, find out the database url of your firebase project and then pass it as an argument to the database function like this

```
dbReference = Firebase.database("database url of ur app").reference;
```

Comment: Thank you. I correct this part, but it doesn't work. I don't see any data.
I don't know if it's a problem, but in the code there is another database's name instead of Firebase, because the location is different.